# Fill combobox in DataGrid with data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I was not able to use the answers from other similar questions. I feel I'm close to a solution, but struggle on one or two points.

- I need a `ComboBoxColumn` in my `DataGrid`.
- the `ComboBoxColumn` shows defaultly the place where an item is stocked right now.
- I should be able to change the place with the `ComboBox`.

Here is the `DataGrid` with the `ComboBox` included:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="goederenZoekenDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Margin="10,315,10,120"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          RowEditEnding="goederenZoekenDataGrid_RowEditEnding">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lotnummerLeverancierColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding LotnummerLeverancier}"
                        Header="Lotnr Leverancier" Width="auto"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="grondstofomschrijvingColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding Grondstofomschrijving}"
                        Header="Grondstof" Width="auto"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="leveranciersNaamColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding LeveranciersNaam}"
                        Header="Leverancier" Width="auto"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="datumLeveringColumn"
                            Header="Datum Levering" Width="auto">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DatumLevering, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="hoeveelheidGeleverdColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding HoeveelheidGeleverd}"
                        Header="Hoeveelheid IN" Width="auto"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="eenheidColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding Eenheid}"
                        Header="Eenheid" Width="auto"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lotnummerINIDColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding LotnummerINID}"
                        Header="Lotnummer INID" Width="auto"/>                  
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="stockINOmschrijvingColumn"
                            Header="Stockplaats IN" Width="auto">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox Name="cmbStockINGrid"
                    Text="{Binding StockINOmschrijving, Mode=Twoway, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsEditable="True" Height="20"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbStockINGrid_SelectionChanged"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="HoeveelheidStockINColumn"
                        Binding="{Binding HoeveelheidStockIN}"
                        Header="Hoeveelheid Stock" Width="auto"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This gives me already the result of the stock place. Good sign. But to fill the `ComboBox` up with the rest of all the places I must have made a mistake since no result is returned. My biggest struggle here is the fact that the `ComboBox`  name used in the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` couldn't be used in the code behind.

```
private void cmbStockINGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox combostockIN = (ComboBox)sender;
    stockPlaatsINViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("stockPlaatsINViewSource")));

    var manager = new LotnummersDBManager();

    using (var conLotnrs = manager.Getconnection())
    using (var comstockin = conLotnrs.CreateCommand())
    {
        comstockin.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comstockin.CommandText = "SELECT StockINOmschrijving FROM StockPlaatsIN order by StockINOmschrijving asc";

        conLotnrs.Open();

        using (var rdrstockin = comstockin.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdrstockin.Read())
            {
                combostockIN.Items.Add(rdrstockin[0]);
            }//while
        } //using rdrStockPlaatsIN
    }//using Conlotnrs and ComStockPlaatsIN
}// cmbStockINGrid_SelectionChanged
```

Result is in [image: this image] Can anyone help me out to fill the ComboBox with the selection from sql?

My StockPlaatsINViewsource comes from the following class:

```
namespace AdoGemeenschap
{
public class StockPlaatsIN : LotnummerIN
{

    private Int32 stockplaatsinidValue;
    private String stockinValue;
    private decimal HoeveelstockinValue; 

    public Int32 StockPlaatsINID
    {
        get { return stockplaatsinidValue; }
        set { stockplaatsinidValue = value; }
    }
    public String StockINOmschrijving
    {
        get { return stockinValue; }
        set { stockinValue = value; }
    }   

    public decimal HoeveelheidStockIN
    {
        get { return HoeveelstockinValue; }
        set { HoeveelstockinValue = value; }
    }


    public StockPlaatsIN(Int32 stockinID, String stockbeschrijving, decimal hoeveelstockin, Int32 lotnrinid):base(lotnrinid)
    {
        this.StockPlaatsINID = stockinID;
        this.StockINOmschrijving = stockbeschrijving;
        this.StockINOmschrijving = stockbeschrijving;
        this.HoeveelheidStockIN = hoeveelstockin;

    }

    public StockPlaatsIN(string stockbeschrijving)
    {
        this.StockINOmschrijving = stockbeschrijving;
    }

}
```

PS: Other possibility that I tried was as follows but I don't even find how to use a `ComboBox`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="stockINOmschrijvingColumn"
                        Header="Stockplaats IN" Width="auto"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StockINOmschrijving, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource stockPlaatsINViewSource}}"/>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that you use to define the StaticResource `stockPlaatsINViewSource`? Anyway, the last row is wrong: if the StaticResource is a list, you should simply write: `ItemsSource="{StaticResource stockPlaatsINViewSource}"`

Comment: When you run the app, does the Output Window give you some error message? Something like "Error data binding" or similar?

Comment: Hi Massimiliano, no it doesn't give an error message. In fact it just stays empty.

Comment: Did you try the modification I suggested to you about ItemsSource?

Comment: I tried yes, but it gives me an error.  Let's say I'm totally stuck even with every explanation I've heard or read already. The StaticResource StockPlaatsInViewSource comes from the following class.

Comment: what error does it give?